# SQL to get sales for same customer with diffente payment type

Tags: sql, oracle, subquery, aggregate-functions, having-clause

I have a Oracle Database and a sales table, follow a small sample:

```
customer | type      |  value
----------------------------------------------
A        | CREDIT    |  20  
A        | DEBIT     |  10
B        | CREDIT    |  50
B        | DEBIT     |  200
C        | CREDIT    |  40
```

I need to find all the sales where the same **customer** have **type** CREDIT AND DEBIT. For example, in this sample, the customer C would be ignored because he doesn't have type CREDIT AND DEBIT.

I'm trying with inner join between two queries using the customer as key:

```
select * from
(select customer, type, value from sales where type IN ('DEBIT')) A
INNER JOIN
(select customer, type, value from sales where type IN ('CREDIT')) B
ON (A.customer = B.customer)
```

The problem with this approach is that, as you can see, the user can choose multiple types (that's why it's an IN clause) and if the user choose more than one type, the join could give duplicated results.

Any idea of a SQL solution for this situation?

Answer (score 0):

If you want entire rows, you can use `exists`:

```
select *
from sales s
where exists (
    select 1 from sales s1 where s1.customer = s.customer and s1.type <> s.type
)
```

If you just want the list of customer that have both type, then you can `group by` and filter with a `having` clause:

```
select customer
from sales
group by customer
having min(type) <> max(type)
```

Both answers implicitly assume that there are just two possible types (credit and debit), as shown in your sample data. If you need to handle more types per customer (say, 4 types per customers), then:

```
select customer
from sales
group by customer
having count(distinct type) = 4
```

Or if you want entire rows:

```
select *
from sales s
where (select count(distinct type) from sales s1 where s1.customer = s.customer) = 4
```

Comment: Thanks!!

That's possible to have more than two possible types, I've used just two to don't increase the size of sample..

Comment: `=4`? I think you mean `=2` in last query.

Answer (score 0):

Another approach could be to group by the customer and check the distinct number of `type`s they have:

```sql
SELECT   customer
FROM     sales
WHERE    type IN ('DEBIT', 'CREDIT')
GROUP BY customer
HAVING   COUNT(DISTINCT type) = 2
```

Comment: I'll try this approach, the only problem will be to concatenate the two filters to put in same IN clause, but it's another issue and another problem related to application! Thanks!!

Comment: Hi Mureinik. I've tested it, the problem is: I need to return the type in this query, if I add the type column, the count will always return 1. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Yet another approach is to use analytical function `count` as follows:

```
Select * from
(select t.*,
        Count(distinct type) over (partition by customer) as cnt
  from sales t Where t.type IN ('DEBIT', 'CREDIT')
) where cnt = 2
```